# Limit jQuery autcomplete result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
 $("#search_customer").autocomplete({

    source: function (request, response) {

         $.ajax({
             url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "sales/get_customers",
             type: 'GET',
             data:request,

             success: function (data) {
                 var object = JSON.parse(data);


                if(object.length!=0){

                $("#add_customer_div").hide();
                 response($.map(object, function (el) {

                     return {
                         label: el.phone,
                         value: el.name,
                         id:    el.CustomerID
                     };
                 }));


                }else{
                  // $("#add_customer_div").show();
                }
             }
         });

    },
    select: function (event, ui) {

        this.value = ui.item.label;


        $(".ui-menu-item").hide();

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Above code is working fine but didn't limit data, it contains thousands of rows , but I want to limit it to 10 or 20 max. i am trying but failed to do it.

Comment: can you adjust your resource to only return the number you want?

Comment: you have to apply limit onto `get_customers` page then

Comment: You can add a parameter like this `sales/get_customers?pageSize=n` and you need to handle that in `get_customers` based on the value of n.

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar you mean that server side pagination ???
if i had to do server side pagination than how can I judge where my intended result contain ???

Comment: you need to write query based on `n` value so that you can track that what data should send to front end.

Answer (score 1):

You could `.slice` your object, to only contain 10-20 items, below is your success callback with a simple slice applied on the object, rest of the code is as you written. This does not utilize a loop like above.

```
success: function(data) {
    var object = JSON.parse(data);


    if (object.length != 0) {

        $("#add_customer_div").hide();
        object = object.slice(0, 10)
        response($.map(object, function(el) {

            return {
                label: el.phone,
                value: el.name,
                id: el.CustomerID
            };
        }));


    } else {
        // $("#add_customer_div").show();
    }
}
```

If you could however (If you have control over the server) more efficient would be to make an endpoint which only returns 10-20 items, this would save you transferring all this data you're not using.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant limit the result sent by api you can use a for loop instead of map like this

```
var result=[];
if(object.length!=0){
   for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
       result.push(object[i])
   }
}
$("#add_customer_div").hide();
 response($.map(result, function (el) {
         return {
                 label: el.phone,
                 value: el.name,
                 id:    el.CustomerID
                 };
  }));
```

Comment: That is a correct "quick fix"... But the *thousands of rows* are still transfered on each request. Limiting server-side could make the requests faster.

Comment: @Louys thats why i said if you cant limit result on the api

Answer (score 0):

To send a "limit" along the ajax request:

```
var limit = 20;  // the amount you wish.

$.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "sales/get_customers" + "?n="+limit,
   //...
```

Then in your PHP ressource:

```
<?php

$default_n = 10;  // a default value in case of omission.

if(isset($_GET['n'])){
  $n = $_GET['n'];
}else{
  $n = $default_n;
}

// Use this $n in the SQL statement.
// Example:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE somecolumn='SomeValue' limit $n";

// ...
```

**Note** that you should **NOT** use the `$n` variable exactly as this example.
You should use mysqli or PDO parametrized query... To avoid SQL injection.
But that is quite out of your question scope.

Comment: this also correct logic bt its little bit length method , for time being above give answered wrok properly , but anyway Thanks alot !